# list all files newer than given timestamp and sort them

Tags: shell-script, find, ls, timestamps

I want to list all files (sorted by date) that are newer than **timestamp** in format `20130207003851` in directory /tmp only. Subdirectories can be omitted.

Using SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11.

The output format should be

```
S0002948.LOG Feb  7 03:28 
S0002935.LOG Feb  7 05:58 
S0002952.LOG Feb  7 09:58 
S0002940.LOG Feb  7 11:58
```

**find /tmp -newermt "7 feb 2013" -ls** lists the files I want but

- how can I use the timestamp in a format 20130207003851
- how can I sort the output?
- how can I display only file name and date. File name first and then the date?

ps I don't want to use touch to create reference file for find

pss

```
find -newermt "20130207003851" -ls
find: I cannot figure out how to interpret `20130207003851' as a date or time
```

Comment: What is `2013007000385` supposed to represent? I guess 2013 is the year, but how do you get from `007000385` to Feb 7?

Comment: @Gilles: Supposed to be `20130207003851`. Didn't copy it correctly or ... sorry for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`find` supports a lot of [date input formats](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html). The simplest format to obtain is YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS. You already have the digits in the right order, all you have to do is extract the first group (`${timestamp%??????}`: take all but the last 6 characters; `${timestamp#????????}`: take all but the first 8 characters), and keep going, appending punctuation then the next group as you go along.

```
timestamp=20130207003851
timestring=${timestamp%??????}; timestamp=${timestamp#????????}
timestring="$timestring ${timestamp%????}"; timestamp=${timestamp#??}
timestring="$timestring:${timestamp%??}:${timestamp#??}"
```

In bash (and ksh and zsh), but not in ash, you can use the more readable `${STRING_VARIABLE:OFFSET:LENGTH}` construct.

```
timestring="${timestamp:0:8} ${timestamp:8:2}:${timestamp:10:2}:${timestamp:12:2}"
```

To sort files by date, print out the file names preceded by the dates and sort that, then strip the date prefix. Use [`-printf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Format-Directives) to control the output format. `%TX` prints a part of the modification time determined by `X`; if `X` is `@`, you get the number of seconds since the Unix epoch. Below I print three tab-separated columns: the time in sortable format, the file name, and the time in human-readable format; `cut -f 2-` removes the first column and the call to `expand` replaces the tab by enough spaces to accommodate all expected file names (adjust 40 as desired). This code assumes you have no newlines or tabs in file names.

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f \
     -newermt "$timestring" -printf '%T@\t%f\t%Tb %Td %TH:%TM\n' |
sort -k1n |
cut -f 2- |
expand -t 40
```

Comment: only the find part `find -newermt "$timestring" -printf '%M@\t%f %Mb %Md %MH:%MM\n'` gives me funny output `-rwxrwxrwx@ S0002975.LOG -rwxrwxrwxb -rwxrwxrwxd -rwxrwxrwxH:-rwxrwxrwxM`

Comment: @Radek Sorry, it's `%T` for the mtime, `%M` is the permissions.

Comment: Beautiful. Works smoothly. My final code is `find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt "20130207 00:38:51" -printf '%T@\t%f-%Tb %Td %TH:%TM\n' | sort -k1n | cut -f 2-` I separated file name and time  by `-` because I will capture the output in php and use - as separator. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Gilles it's awesome, but if you explain timestring , it will help more..

Comment: @RahulPatil Done. I also added a more readable bash method.

Comment: @Radek Note that it's dangerous to assume filenames don't contain this or that character when dealing with files in a world writable directory. You may be introducing a path to privilege escalation here depending on what you do with that output. More generally, doing automated processing on a world writable directory is a mine field, proceed with extreme care.

Answer (score 5):

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
newer() {
  local t
  zstat -A t -F %Y%m%d%H%M%S +mtime -- $REPLY && (( t >= timestamp ))
}
timestamp=20130207003851
print -rl -- /tmp/*(D.Om+newer)
```

The `newer` function returns true for files newer than `$timestamp` (note that `zsh`'s `zstat` doesn't support subsecond accuracy though).

Then all we do is use `zsh` globbing qualifiers: `D` to include dot files, `.` to only consider regular files, `Om` to order on modification time, and `+newer` to call the `newer` function to determine which file to select.

If you want to display the file timestamps as well, you can change `newer` to:

```
newer() {
  local t
  zstat -A t -F %Y%m%d%H%M%S +mtime -- $REPLY &&
    REPLY+=$'\t'$t &&
    (( t >= timestamp ))
}
```

Note though that the result of the filename generation will include the timestamps which means you can't use those as filenames any more.

Comment: this won't work over `ssh`, for instance.